# Is there any way to get the list of available equipment in exchange server?

Tags: c#, exchange-server

I am trying to get all the resources available in exchange service. To get the list of rooms I am using the below code and it is working fine

```
EmailAddressCollection myRoomLists = service.GetRoomLists();
```

Now the same way, I want to get the list of equipments ?
Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an LDAP search using the property msExchRecipientDisplayType as a filter.  Room mailboxes have this property set to 7 and equipment mailboxes have it set to 8.

There's a notion of a user mailbox, a room mailbox and an equipment mailbox. You might not be able to find equipment mailboxes using EWS, but you might need to search Active Directory.

Reference: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4ff04c60-48c2-4a69-ab75-2383e73bfde2/e2010ewsxmljavahow-to-list-all-resource-mailboxes-meeting-room-in-exchange-web-service-2010?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment

Comment: Exchange server is not providing any direct method to find the equipment like roomilst ?

Comment: No, not everything can be gotten from EWS. Some from AD, some from MAPI